# Enviar Correos Gmail

Tags: email, google-chrome, gmail, smtp

Buenas estoy desarrollando un sistema ERP el cual envía correos usando STMP de Gmail, puedo enviar todo bien!, pero para lograr enviar los correos tuve q quitarle todas las cuestiones de seguridad a la cuenta gmail.

Mi pregunta es como hacer que mi ERP pueda estar como aplicacion de terceros en gmail, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con que tema busco informacion al Respecto?