# Enviar Correos Gmail desde vb o C#

Tags: c#, vb, gmail, smtp

Buenas estoy desarrollando un sistema ERP el cual envía correos usando STMP de Gmail, puedo enviar todo bien!, pero para lograr enviar los correos tuve q quitarle todas las cuestiones de seguridad a la cuenta gmail.

Mi pregunta es como hacer que mi ERP pueda estar como aplicacion de terceros en gmail, algo asi:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este Codigo:

```
Dim mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
mail.From = New MailAddress(txtDe.Text)
Dim _att As New Attachment(strRutaAbsolutaFile)
mail.To.Add(txtPara.Text)
mail.Subject = txtAsunto.Text
mail.Body = txtCuerpo.Text
mail.Attachments.Add(_att)

Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient

Smtp_Server.Host = txtSMPT_Host.Text '"smtp.gmail.com"
Smtp_Server.Port = numSMPT_Puerto.Value '25 ''465; //587
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(mstrMail_Autenticacion, mstrPassword_Autenticacion)

Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = chkSMPT_SSL.Checked 'True

            Smtp_Server.Send(mail)
```

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, las preguntas basadas solo en opiniones pueden ser eliminadas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Enviar Correos Gmail](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328945/enviar-correos-gmail)

Comment: @Fernankin justamente yo hice esa pregunta tambien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `Gmail` vas a necesitar de una cuenta que pueda autenticarse para enviar el mail, no importa si es tuya o si es el cliente que usa la aplicaicon quien proporciona usuario y password de la cuenta de gmail para enviar el correo

Si quieres que sea independiente vas a necesitar un servicio independiente como podria ser

[SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/smtp-service/)

puedes usar el servicio de `smtp` o la `webapi`

[SendGrid WebApi](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html)

la cuestion es que creas una cuenta para la aplicacion que estas desarrollando y sera independiente de una cuenta propia como sucede en `gmail`

`Gmail` esta pensado para cuentas `particulares`, en cambio `SendGrid` es un `servicio`

Por ejemplo si estas desarrollando una app cloud en Azure debes usar servicio como SendGrid para el envio de mail, no funcionan las cuentas de gmail

Cuentas con librerias en nuget para que el desarrollo sea mas simple

[SendGrid nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/)

Nota: Recomende SendGrid porque es el que conozco, pero si buscas hay otros similares